# How can I add a cache manifest to a Meteor app?

Tags: meteor

Well, adding it will be no problem, but how can I generate the cache manifest? I would need to somehow get the paths to the combined CSS and JS that Meteor generates. http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/#manifests

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update:**

As user1506145 said:

```
meteor add appcache
```

https://atmospherejs.com/meteor/appcache

**This answer is out of date:**

The answer lies in the bundler package, I autogenerated a manifest file there.
You can get a full list of css and js files by hooking into: `bundle.css` and `bundle.js.client`

Once you have managed to get them a manifest file you will need to do the following with a manifestcontent var you have generated (dont forget to exclude from caching all the meteor urls needed):

```
buffer.files.client_cacheable['manifest.appcache'] = new Buffer(manifestcontent);
```

This will have your application serving the appcache file. Then you can edit /app/lib/app.html.in to add the reference in.

My issue when I did this was that I wasn't able to stale the cache often enough so it ended up with an application messed up on reload from the server.

Comment: I wasn't able to delete my own answer, however below is much easier.

Answer (score 2):

You may automatically generate and include the manifest by adding the appcache package.

`meteor add appcache`

https://atmospherejs.com/meteor/appcache