# Can meteor application be launched offline

Tags: meteor

Can meteor application be launched offline, when no server connection is active, 
for example from html5 application cache in browser.

Or being saved to offline folder.

of course no data propagation to server, but maybe some local cache.

EDIT: how about saving events to local storage when offine?

Comment: **Related:** http://www.w3.org/TR/offline-webapps/ (This is interesting, would be nice if Meteor supports this one day)

Comment: There's a good answer to the same question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10135606/can-meteor-app-to-work-offline

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, theoretically, this should be doable by creating a HTML5 cache manifest. I asked about this here:

[How can I add a cache manifest to a Meteor app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10668687/how-can-i-add-a-cache-manifest-to-a-meteor-app)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same query. This is worth looking at for persisting your data offline:-

https://github.com/awwx/meteor-offline-data

Answer (score 0):

Meteor has an appcache package (check the docs) and it currently being used in the docs itself.