# Simple way to add a cache manifest to a Meteor app?

Tags: html, node.js, offline, meteor, cache-manifest

I would like to make the Meteor (meteor.com) app load without connectivity to the meteor server(offline) via cache manifest.

I think a similar question has already been asked here:
[How can I add a cache manifest to a Meteor app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10668687/how-can-i-add-a-cache-manifest-to-a-meteor-app) 
but I couldn't follow their solution (more on this below).

Is there a simple way to include a cache manifest on a Meteor app and have the manifest populated with all the meteor assets?

---

From the related post my questions are:

- > You can get a full list of css and js files by hooking into: bundle.css and bundle.js.client

  What is involved in "hooking into" those files? How should I proceed?
- > buffer.files.client_cacheable['manifest.appcache'] = new Buffer(manifestcontent);

  What does this do and where should it go?
- > Then you can edit /app/lib/app.html.in to add the reference in

  Is this just the `manifest="/application.manifest"` bit in the html tag?

Comment: Just type `meteor add appcache`

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10668687/how-can-i-add-a-cache-manifest-to-a-meteor-app/10679062#10679062

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would find it easier to build your manifest from outside, using [ManifestR](http://westciv.com/tools/manifestR/). The page also included how it should be added into the `<head>` of each page.